# How to determine the amount of entries an array has?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to loop through an array backwards, so I figured I could try

```
$Array = Array("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five");
For ($Entry = Amount_of_values($Array); $Entry = 0; $Entry = $Entry-1){
    Echo $Array[$Entry] . " "; //Should be Five Four Three Two One
}
```

but I have no idea how to retrieve the amount of values in an array ( *Amount_of_values($Array)* in the example). What's the function I'm looking for?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Little additional question: why should it be $Entry >= 0 in the for loop, isn't the last thing I want to output $Array[0]?

Comment: You might want to rephrase that to say "the size or length of an array", or "the number of entries". Amount usually refers to other things, like a sum.

Comment: There is an error in your for loop, at `$Entry = 0`. This should probably be `$Entry >= 0`.

Comment: *(reference)* [Array Functions](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php)

Comment: As an aside, I think you have a VB/ASP background. In PHP, keywords and variable names generally start with a lowercase letter. Also, `$entry = $entry - 1` is more concisely written as `$entry--`.

Comment: Yes I wasn't sure about entries at first, fixed title.

Comment: @Sjoerd, you are right, but I don't understand why. Shouldn't the last thing I want to echo be $Array[0]?

Comment: @Chris - what your code does at present each time through the loop is set the value of `$Entry` to zero (a single `=` assigns) - you probably wanted to check whether it was greater than or equal to zero, which you do with `>=`. You might find the explanation of `expr2` in the docs (http://us2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a better way of doing what your code snippet does - using  [`implode`](http://www.php.net/implode) and [`array_reverse`](http://www.php.net/array_reverse):

```
$Array = Array("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five");
echo implode(" ", array_reverse($Array)); // Should be Five Four Three Two One
```

The answer to your actual question though, is if you want to count the number of entries in an array, you want [`count`](http://www.php.net/count).

Comment: `echo implode(array_reverse($Entries));`, since his original array is the other way round.

Comment: @janmoesen - where did `$Entries` come from? Why are you using `implode` without a value for the glue?

Comment: Thanks Dominic and Jan for answering the question and providing an alternative.

Comment: oh dear, that missing glue was an oversight on my part. As for `$Entries`, that was the OP's variable. All I wanted to point out was the `array_reverse`, which was there in your answer all along. Man, I think my brain was malfunctioning++.

Comment: @janmoesen - ah, no, rest assured your brain is functioning fine. My original answer didn't include `array_reverse`, I added that as an edit within the 5 minute window.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [`count`](http://www.php.net/count):

```
print count($Array);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want:

```
count($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

use [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) php function

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
count($Array)
```

Comment: Why use the alias instead of the direct function?  In other languages, `sizeof` means different things depending upon the data type, so why add the layer of possible confusion (especially since it adds nothing over `count()`... http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php

Comment: Ok, why did SO not record that edit...  The post originally had `sizeof($Array)` instead of `count($Array)`, and that's what my response above is to...

Comment: @ircmaxell - edits aren't recorded if they are within 5 minutes from the initial post (just in case you, or someone else thought it was a bug).

Answer (score 1):

try `count($Array)`:

```
For ($Entry = count($Array); $Entry = 0; $Entry = $Entry-1){
        Echo $Array[$Entry] . " "; //Should be Five Four Three Two One
    }
```